# entering names dynamically using php for loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

ive got number of textboxes that will be filled in with name from database.

i create 5 textinputs, using for.. loop

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
  echo '<input type="text" value="">';
}
```

my question is how do i enter the names to the each textboxes dynamically.

i tried:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM att WHERE id_bs_res='$id_bs_res'");  

for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    while($r = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$r['att_name'].'">';
    }
}
```

if there are 3 names in database, it will only show 3 instead of 5 textboxes? 
i want it shows all the textboxes even if the rest of textboxes will be blank.

```
sample textboxes
1. names
2. names
3. names
4. ------
5. ------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the inner while loop.

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM att WHERE id_bs_res='$id_bs_res'");  

for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    $r = $q->fetch_assoc();
    echo '<input type="text" value="'.isset($r['att_name'])?$r['att_name']:''.'">';
}
```

of course, better check count of the returned rows, and do not call fetch_assoc() after you've displayed the 3 rows, just output the next 2

Answer (score 1):

Not always a big fan of using function returns and setting a variable inside an if statement, but this should do what you want:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM att WHERE id_bs_res='$id_bs_res'");  

for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    if($r = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$r['att_name'].'">';
    } else {
        echo '<input type="text" value="">';
    }
}
```

Basically, if there's a valid row, it will echo an input box with the proper values, if there isn't it will simply echo a blank box.

Comment: This is effectively the same as Darhazer's answer, just without using a ternary

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
I think that solves all youre problems :) (if i'm correct)

Oh, and I don't understand youre last question? Do you want to show atleast 5 boxes, even when there are only 3 names? Or not?